# How can I connect my HP LaserJet Pro M102W to a WiFi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

I would very much like to set up and use my LaserJet Pro M102w. I have not had any luck with the online instructions. They usually begin by saying “Make sure your device is connected to the same WiFi network as the printer,” but the instructions are not clear on how to connect the printer to the WiFi network in the first place.

I did find one page that detailed it, and it said something like “Hold the Information and WiFi buttons at the same time until the WiFi light flashes.” My printer does not have an “Information” button that I can see, it has a WiFi button and button with what looks like a piece of paper with a downwards arrow on it and a red X (a paper jam button, maybe?). I tried holding them simultaneously for a bit, this did cause the WiFi button to blink in blue, and a circle on the button panel to blink in green. The instructions said I should press the WPS button on my WiFI router. I tried that, but, it did not seem to cause the printer to connect to the WiFi.

Also, I don’t know how to check if it’s connected, since the instructions say that holding those two previously named buttons would print out a WiFi report, but for me, it just prints a paper that says LaserJet m101-106 Series, with a big picture of a printer.

So, how do I get started? I need to connect my LaserJer M102W to my WiFi network. Any advice?

Comment: Did you install the HP Smart App on your IOS? You need that for AirPrint.  Is your IOS up to date (version 13 now)

Comment: @John As far as I can see the OP is already struggling with connecting the printer to WiFi. This should be solved before looking into AirPrint (which, I assume, will work as soon as the printer actually *is* connected).

Comment: @John The iOS is up to date. I didn't install the app. I'll check it out. But all the instructions seems to begin with connecting the printer to WiFi (as nohillside said).

Comment: I agree that you should try setting up the driver on a regular computer and make that work.  Then try AirPrint.  You may (if you are able to do this) setting up a static IP address on the printer to prevent it from getting “lost”